# What is the euquivalent of Maven Tycho to build NetBeans Applications?

Tags: maven, netbeans, build, eclipse-rcp, rcp

More generally, how are bigger (meaning lots of dependencies or many modules) RCP Applications build?

Eclipse RCP uses Tycho and p2. What does NB use to build apps headless?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/mojohaus/nbm-maven-plugin with maven (archetypes and support available via netbeans project wizards)

or the default ant-based project types (again available via the netbeans module project wizards)